# Can random variables have the same distribution but different conditional distributions?

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-probability

Can two equally distributed random variables $X$, $Y$, defined over the same probability space have different conditional distributions relative to some $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{A}$, so that $X\sim Y$ but $P\left(E\left(\left.f(X)\right|\mathcal{A}\right)\neq E\left(\left.f(Y)\right|\mathcal{A}\right)\right)>0$ for some integrable $f$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure: take some i.i.d. random variables $X$ and $Y$, and $\mathcal A=\sigma(X)$.

Comment: Right, thanks! The reason i asked was that i read the following claim: If $E(\prod_{i=1}^n f_i(X_i)|\mathcal{A})=\prod_{i=1}^n E(f_i(X_1)|\mathcal{A})$ a.s. for all measurable, bounded $f_i$, then the $X_i$ are conditionally i.i.d. given $\mathcal{A}$. In the context where this claim was made the $X_i$ were identically distributed, so i tried to prove the claim by showing that if $X_1\sim X_i$, then $E(f_i(X_1)|\mathcal{A})=E(f_i(X_i)|\mathcal{A})$. But as you pointed out, this argument is invalid. Now i realize that i did not need to use the a-priori $X_i$ distributions to prove the claim.